# Samsung Galaxy S7: dark photos with sunlight

Tags: applications, camera, photos, samsung-galaxy-s7

I recently bought a Samsung Galaxy S7.

The camera is really great at night, but at daytime the photos are turning out way too dark. I tried tweaking the settings, also in manual mode but didn't help.

Any ideas how to improve my daytime photos?

2nd question: is there a good hdr app (real hdr, not just an image filter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samsung's camera app may have developed more options since mine, an S3, but the settings allow configuration of 'Effects' and 'Scene'.

'Effects' controls color and warmness, and specific washouts or enhanced colors, while,

'Scene' implies filtering based on the usage of the device in conjunction to surroundings. It takes into consideration emphasized lighting (outdoor, dawn, sunset), light dispersion conditions (beach, snow), diminished lighting (night, fireworks), focal lighting (candlelight, backlight), need for speed during exposure (i.e. sport events).

Used separately or in conjunction, they could resolve your issues.